# How can i fetch all id names inside a div

Tags: javascript

how can i fetch all id names inside a div and push them in a array ?

Example

```
//elements
<div id="container">
     <div id="number1"></div>
     <div id="number2"></div>
     <div id="number3"></div>
</div>

//fetch id names
while (thereAreIdNamesInsideDiv){
    array.push(idName)
}

//the array
array["number1", "number2", "number3"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use querySelectorAll and `map` which will return an array. Inside `map` callback use `getAttribute` to get the element id

```js
const arr = [...document.getElementById('container').querySelectorAll('div')]
.map(item => item.getAttribute('id'));
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="number1"></div>
  <div id="number2"></div>
  <div id="number3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer it worked, im still a beginner in js, why do i need 3 dots before document.getElementById('container') for it to work ?

Comment: Check [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)